# Can't upload files larger than 15mb in php form on server

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, internal-server-error, dedicated-server

Domain = benchmarkstudio.biz

Dedicated Hostgator Server

PHP Version **5.4.45**

Can check the info from the below link.
https://benchmarkstudio.biz/phpinfo.php

Issue
I have created a test form in the below link where it uploads the attached file in the directory given and prints the message.
https://benchmarkstudio.biz/portal/upload-test/upload.php

Note It is an open link so my dev community can try it too.

When I try files less than 10MB it gets successfully uploaded. But when I try files larger than 20MB it gives me

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@benchmarkstudio.transdata.biz to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

(I can't find any error logs related to this.)

Although php.ini settings are:

```
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 32M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

**upload.php code is below**

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="my_file" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

upload_file.php code is below

```
<?php
if (($_FILES['my_file']['name']!="")){
// Where the file is going to be stored
    $target_dir = "upload/";
    $file = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $path = pathinfo($file);
    $filename = $path['filename'];
    $ext = $path['extension'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;
 
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
        echo "Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using such an outdated version of PHP? I'm not saying it's relevant, it just seems a strange choice.

Comment: I believe this is an encoding issue - the file to upload is base64-encoded which makes it larger, then it has various headers and separators added in, all of which could take a 20Mb file above your post_max_size.

Comment: Also, as `upload_max_size` is the maximum size of each individual upload, and `post_max_size` is the maximum size of all of them, why is your post_max_size smaller than your upload_max_size?

Comment: Also this final part of the error report `Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.` Makes me think its a seperate issue and related to a badly coded ErrorDocument [See the Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Comment: In some case (such as if you use PHP FPM), you may need to increase [configuration in Apache](https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-exceeds-maxrequestlen). For more configurations, please [read the document on Apache website](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen).

Comment: @droopsnoot yes its an outdated version and needs to be upgraded but firstly, I want to solve this issue. post_max_size is now 512M and upload_max_filesize = 256M now. Thank you for the suggestion. Still, the issue is there.